# Direct command line input runs command but bash script does not

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am able to successfully run

```
/opt/hbase/hbase_current/bin/hbase
```

on the command line, when connected to a GNU/Linux cluster.

However, when I put this command as a line of a bash script, the error is:

```
: No such file or directoryopt/hbase/hbase_current/bin/hbase
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I added a header to the bash script based on the results of "which bash", I get the following error:

```
bash: ./file.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ENTITY="'A.B.C'"
HBASE_SHELL="/opt/hbase/hbase_current/bin/hbase"
FILE="A.B.C.txt"
/opt/hbase/hbase_current/bin/hbase
#echo "scan $ENTITY" | $HBASE_SHELL > $FILE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, you have DOS-style CR/LF at the end of your lines. You can see them as they show up as `^M`

Do this:

```
tr -d '\r' < file.sh > newfile.sh
chmod +x newfile.sh
./newfile.sh
```

The `tr` command is started with `-d` which means **delete** all occurrences of whatever follows, which in this case is the sequence representing Carriage Return (`CR`).

Comment: @La-comadreja Also check out the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). This is troubleshooting step #1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have copied the script from a Windows box. Try dos2unix on the file to remove the Windows line endings:

```
$ dos2unix file.sh
```

(`sudo apt-get install dos2unix` if you don't have it)